# Cursor Using Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, input, cursor

I am trying to create a simple cursor in Oracle that will loop through the columns of a table and store the column name and data type. I want the table name to be dynamic using an input. I am receiving a whole bunch of different error messages when trying to compile the procedure (variables not declared, etc). I must have my basic structure wrong. This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DV
(
TABLENAME IN VARCHAR2
)
 authid current_user

AS

  sql_qx varchar2(5000);
  curTab varchar2(5000);
  curCol varchar2(5000);
  curTyp varchar2(5000);


  BEGIN

  sql_qx := 'DECLARE CURSOR tblCur IS 
              SELECT table_name,
                    column_name,
                    data_type
              FROM  user_tab_columns
              WHERE table_name =  ''' || TABLENAME || '''';

  execute immediate sql_qx;


    IF NOT tblCur%ISOPEN THEN
    OPEN tblCur;
    END IF;

    FETCH tblCur INTO curTab, curCol, curTyp;
    WHILE tblCur%FOUND THEN
      LOOP

         dbms_output.put_line(tblCur.curTab || ' ' ||tblCur.curCol || ' ' ||tblCur.curTyp); 

   FETCH tblCur INTO curTab, curCol, curTyp;

   END LOOP;
   END DV;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DV (TABLENAME IN VARCHAR2) authid current_user
AS
  curTab varchar2(5000);
  curCol varchar2(5000);
  curTyp varchar2(5000);

  CURSOR tblCur IS 
    SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type
    FROM  user_tab_columns
    WHERE table_name = TABLENAME;

BEGIN
    IF NOT tblCur%ISOPEN THEN
        OPEN tblCur;
    END IF;

    LOOP
        FETCH tblCur INTO curTab, curCol, curTyp;
        EXIT WHEN tblCur%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line(curTab || ' ' || curCol || ' ' || curTyp); 
    END LOOP;
END DV;
```

You don't even need an explicit cursor here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DV (TABLENAME IN VARCHAR2) authid current_user
AS
BEGIN
    FOR c IN (SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type
              FROM  user_tab_columns
              WHERE table_name = TABLENAME) 
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(c.table_name || ' ' || c.column_name || ' ' || c.data_type); 
    END LOOP;
END DV;
```